# Is there a simple way to read auto-assigned values on insert using php mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an in-house PHP class that I use for Object Relational Mapping.  I would like to add an improvement to it though, and I'm not sure how to go about it:

When a new record is created, it has a flag marking it as such.  When the record is saved, it checks for that flag; if the flag is set, then any fields that were flagged as "auto_increment", are assigned the mysqli::insert_id value.

What I'd like to do is update this so that ~any~ field that the database updates on the save (e.g. TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()), gets assigned back to the object.

So, the only way that comes to mind is as follows:

- Save the record
- Grab the auto-increment field if applicable
- Reload the record with another SELECT

I guess that would work, but it seems a bit roundabout to me.  It also depends on none of the key fields being automatically assigned.

Is there any way to get auto-assigned values other than insert_id from the mysqli object after saving the record?

Comment: You could read the table structure and note down the default values. Then you could set the values as default in your objects after saving it. However this will be a huge amount of work and your way might be more fast forward.
You could also look into an ORM (e.g. Doctrine2) as they offer such features.

Comment: Existing ORM's like doctrine do something not too dissimilar, [in a roundabout way](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/06a00cf073c0c22e9b14f5b625a490478e0259ae/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1020). The easiest way for you to get things like an `onUpdate` timestamp is to add getters and setters to your objects that set the new values PHP-side, and not to rely on MySQL default values as much, but that brings with it a whole series of other problems... TL;TR: I wouldn't worry about it too much